# Difference between Test and test in sbt

Tags: scala, configuration, sbt

For example i can write in my build:

```
name in Test := "some name"
name in test := "some name"
```

and both would perfectly work. So what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case `Test` is of type configuration. As it is sad in the official docs to sbt:

```
A configuration defines a flavor of build, potentially with its own classpath, sources, generated packages, etc.
```

and the second `test` is just a simple task defined in the global scope.
If you call `inspect test` in sbt it will show that `test` just *executes all tests* and is provided by global scope `*:test`, it's like an aggregator of all test tasks. The whole task tree under test you can see with `inspect tree task` command.
To inspect `Test` configuration you should call `inspect test:configuration`, as you can see it just provides configuration for test scope in your project.
So `name in test` and `name in Test` have the same result

Comment: There is a good explanation of sbt on [scopes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html) and official sources are also a good source of experience =)